# How to add json complex format to html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I used AJAX and get JSON response then I want to map json to table html 
like

# | TypeID | TypeDesc | CreateBy

1  | 000001 |  AAAAAA  | Adam

2  | 000002 |  BBBBBB  | James

This is my json

```
{
    "records": [{
        "type_id": 000001,
        "type_desc": "AAAAAA ",
        "type_createby": "Adam"
    }, {
        "type_id": 000002,
        "type_desc": "BBBBBB",
        "type_createby": "James"
    }, {
        "type_id": 000003,
        "type_desc": "CCCCCC",
        "type_createby": "Sam"
    }]
}
```

and this is I'm trying

```
success: function (response) {
    $('#table-container').html("");

    $.each(response, function (index) {
        var tableRow = "";
        var row = 1;
        tableRow = $('<tr/>');
        tableRow.append("<td>" + row + "</td>");
        row = row + 1;
        tableRow.append("<td>" + response[index].type_id + "</td>");
        tableRow.append("<td>" + response[index].type_desc + "</td>");
        tableRow.append("<td>" + response[index].type_createby + "</td>");

        $('#table-container').append(tableRow);
    });
},
```

My display show the table but the data still show "undefined". There are two questions I have.

1.How to define the correct data ?

2.How to loop to show 5 row and get paging with javascript ?

Comment: Make sure `response` is an object, not a JSON string, then iterate through `response.records` instead of `response`. Then just check if `index` is greater than four and in that case return false from the `each`'s callback. Notice, that you need to declare `row` outside of the `each`'s callback if you want it to keep counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over `response` that is not a array. Iterate through `response.records` instead of `response`.

```
 success: function(response){
                 $('#table-container').html("");
                 $.each (response.records , function (index,record) {
                     var tableRow = "";
                     var row = 1 ;
                     tableRow = $('<tr/>');
                     tableRow.append("<td>" + row + "</td>");
                     row = row + 1 ;
                     tableRow.append("<td>" + record.type_id + "</td>");
                     tableRow.append("<td>" + record.type_desc + "</td>");
                     tableRow.append("<td>" + record.type_createby + "</td>");
                     $('#table-container').append(tableRow);
           });
     },
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
var response = {
 "records": [{
  "type_id": 000001,
  "type_desc": "AAAAAA ",
  "type_createby": "Adam"
 }, {
  "type_id": 000002,
  "type_desc": "BBBBBB",
  "type_createby": "James"
 }, {
  "type_id": 000003,
  "type_desc": "CCCCCC",
  "type_createby": "Sam"
 }]
}

$('#table-container').html("");
  $.each (response.records , function (index,record) {
 var tableRow = "";
 var row = 1 ;
tableRow = $('<tr/>');
tableRow.append("<td>" + row + "</td>");
row = row + 1 ;
tableRow.append("<td>" + record.type_id + "</td>");
tableRow.append("<td>" + record.type_desc + "</td>");
tableRow.append("<td>" + record.type_createby + "</td>");
$('#table-container').append(tableRow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-container"></table>
```

Comment: Thank you!!  I'm adapt code for a little but this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like following. You need to iterate `response.records` and you need to access value of object like `value.type_id` not by index in `$.each` loop

```js
var response = {
 "records": [{
  "type_id": 000001,
  "type_desc": "AAAAAA ",
  "type_createby": "Adam"
 }, {
  "type_id": 000002,
  "type_desc": "BBBBBB",
  "type_createby": "James"
 }, {
  "type_id": 000003,
  "type_desc": "CCCCCC",
  "type_createby": "Sam"
 }]
}

       $.each(response.records, function(value){
        console.log(`Type ID: ${value.type_id}`)
        console.log(`Type Desc: ${value.type_desc}`)
        console.log(`Type Created By: ${value.type_createby}`)

       });
     //success: function(response){
     //        $('#table-container').html("");
     //        $.each (response.records, function (value) {
     //            var tableRow = "";
     //            var row = 1 ;
     //            tableRow = $('<tr/>');
     //            tableRow.append("<td>" + row + "</td>");
     //            row = row + 1 ;
     //            tableRow.append("<td>" + value.type_id + "</td>");
     //           tableRow.append("<td>" + value.type_desc + "</td>");
     //            tableRow.append("<td>" + value.type_createby + "</td>");
     //            $('#table-container').append(tableRow);
     // });
 //},
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 2. How to loop to show 5 row and get paging with javascript ?

If you need to add advanced interaction controls
to your HTML tables, take a look at datatables
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

Give a try working with [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), please take a look to this live example

```js
const dataset = {
        "records": [{
            "type_id": 000001,
            "type_desc": "AAAAAA ",
            "type_createby": "Adam"
        }, {
            "type_id": 000002,
            "type_desc": "BBBBBB",
            "type_createby": "James"
        }, {
            "type_id": 000003,
            "type_desc": "CCCCCC",
            "type_createby": "Sam"
        }]
    };

function getRows(records) {
    const rows = records.map((data, index) => {
        return `
            <tr>
                <td>${++index}</td>
                <td>${data.type_id}</td>
                <td>${data.type_desc}</td>
                <td>${data.type_createby}</td>
            </tr>`;
    }).join('');

    return rows;
}

function getTable(rows) {
    const table = `
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>TypeID</th>
                    <th>TypeDesc</th>
                    <th>CreateBy</th>
                </tr>
            <thead>

            <tbody>
                ${rows}
            <tbody>
        </table>`;

    return table;
}

function renderTable(dataset) {
    const rows = getRows(dataset.records);
    const table = getTable(rows);

    document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = table;
}

renderTable(dataset);
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use "`response.records`";

   if (response && response.records) {
     $.each(response.records, function (index, value) {
       var tableRow = "";
       var row = 1;
       tableRow = $('');
       tableRow.append("" + row + "");
       row = row + 1;
       tableRow.append("" + value.type_id + "");
       tableRow.append("" + value.type_desc + "");
       tableRow.append("" + value.type_createby + "");
       $('#table-container').append(tableRow);
     });
   }
2. Paging is implemented differently depending on what custom table control is used.